# php - get string between two HTML elements

Tags: php, string

I have the following function:

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = " ".$string;
    $ini = strpos($string,$start);
    if ($ini == 0) return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}
```

I passing in the following information over to this function:

```
$result = scraped HTML page;
$name = get_string_between($result, '<div class="model ww"> ',' </div>');
$name= strtok($name, "\n");
```

I expect the following results:

`$name = 'XM1014 | Bone Machine (Well-Worn)';`

The whole section is as follows:

```
<div class="modal ww"> XM1014 | Bone Machine (Well-Worn) </div>
```

Comment: You really shouldn't parse HTML like this. Use [a PHP DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) instead.

Comment: I'm scraping a page protected by cloudflare. Python script to bypass this which return the page content to php. Correct me if I'm wrong however I don't believe I can use a PHP DOM parser in this case.

Comment: You're scraping a page and getting the DOM, you should use a DOM parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code

```
    function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
        $ar=array();
        $ar=explode($start,$string);
        $ar1=explode($end,$ar[0]);
        return implode("",$ar1);        
    }   
   $result = "<div class='modal ww'> XM1014 | Bone Machine (Well-Worn) </div>";
   $text_result=get_string_between($result, '<div class="model ww"> ',' </div>');
   print_r($text_result);
```

parse html with simple html dom. 
here is short example

```
 $html = new simple_html_dom();

// Load HTML from a string
$html->load('<html><body>
<div>test1</div>
<div>test2</div>
</body></html>');

foreach($html->find('div') as $element)
       print_r($element->plaintext);
```

for working above code you need to include [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/?source=typ_redirect) file 
So you can get content between all div. 
You can read more [here](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_quickstart)

Finally  your function will be

```
function get_string_between($string){
        $result=array();
        $html = new simple_html_dom();
        $html->load($string);

        foreach($html->find('div') as $element)
            array_push($result,$element->plaintext);    

        return $result;
 }   
       $result = "<div class='modal ww'> XM1014 | Bone Machine (Well-Worn) </div>";
       $text_result=get_string_between($result);
       print_r($text_result);
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This works when:

`$result = "<div class='modal ww'> XM1014 | Bone Machine (Well-Worn) </div>";`

However `$result` contains a whole html page, which doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: which are other possibilities requirements ? please tell me so that i can update code

Comment: `$name` returns the whole page when passed through your function.

There are no other requirements, the string I'm looking for will always lie between `<div class="modal ww"> </div>` on the page.

Comment: Thanks I have checked that I have updated the answer now you can get content between <div>.

Comment: Possible to amend the first section to function correctly?

Comment: No, Sorry is this not possible without the DOM Parser?

Comment: I think DOM Parser is best solution for your problem. You should go with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can of course use a regexp, but there are libraries which will do the job quicker and easier. Try using a HTML dom parser, or [phquery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) which is an implementation of jquery lib in php. It's also [available for Composer](https://packagist.org/packages/electrolinux/phpquery). So if you're familiar with jquery syntax, you can find it very neat.

Get the html you need using this:
$html = pq('.modal.ww')->html();